# How can I inspect DYLIB contents in terms of size?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, cmake, dylib

After moving from a manually created Xcode project to a CMake-generated Xcode C++ project, my compiled binary [DYLIB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_filename_extensions_(A%E2%80%93E)#D) size has grown significantly: from about 35 MB to about 53 MB.

All the compilation and linking settings I could compare in Xcode projects look pretty much the same (including vs. not including debug symbols, optimization levels, etc.). I wonder if there are any tools to inspect DYLIB contents - what occupies size in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally go with [nm](https://web.archive.org/web/20160316222941/https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nm.1.html) tool. You can inspect any DYLIB file iteratively, section-by-section or just print everything:

```
nm -a /path/to/my/lib.dylib
```

Comment: Thanks! That indeen has shown that the number of symbols is 2x bigger in the big version.
I have also found bloaty which helped to identify that the most space is taken by strings and symbol table: https://github.com/google/bloaty/blob/master/doc/using.md